# Tumblr Oauth returning 401 on API v2

Tags: json, api, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to set up an automatic tumblr post every time I add something new to my website. I'm using the following code:

```
$conskey = "APIKEY";
$conssec = "APISECRET";

$tumblr_blog = "blogname.tumblr.com";
$to_be_posted = "This is the text to be posted";

$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/".$tumblr_blog."/post", array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>$to_be_posted), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);

$result = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());

if($result->meta->status == 200){
    echo 'Success!';
}
```

As far as I can tell this is all formatted correctly. However this is the first time I've tried to connect up to a JSON API using Oauth so I'm not totally confident in what I'm doing.

This is the exact error I'm receiving:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in /home/public_html/edge/tumblr.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/edge/tumblr.php(35): OAuth->fetch('http://api.tumb...', Array, 'POST') #1 /home/public_html/edge/index.php(95): include('/home/...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/edge/tumblr.php on line 35
```

Line 35 is the line beginning with $oauth->fetch.

Thanks for any help :-)

**EDIT**
I've solved the issue by substituting my previous code with the example on [this page](http://vigrond.com/blog/2012/02/04/oauth-extension-php-and-the-tumblr-api/)